# How to parsing string to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a problem parsing string to json.
steps i do :

I have string data encoded in cookie
to get the string i use like:

```
var data = Base64.decode('W3sidCI6MTM4NTg5MjE4MDAwMCwiZiI6MSwiayI6ImZzZGYifV0$')
```

now the variable data equals to:

```
"{"testes":[{"d":1386081060000,"f":1,"t":"da"},{"d":1386081060000,"f":1,"t":"test"}]}"
```

then i want to parse the `data` string to json 
so i am trying to do

```
JSON.parse(data)
```

And got an error. I think it's because of the double quotes in start and the end. 
Can someone help me with that?

Comment: You have an extra comma and no property after it. Try removing it.

Comment: not a vaild json... vaild> '[{"enc":"dsad"}]'

Comment: If you have an error message then you should always include that in your question

Answer (score 1):

You can validate json by your self online here http://jsonlint.com/

Valid format is as below

```
[
    {
        "enc": "dsad"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are fine, but try to remove the trailing comma:

Change

```
"[{"enc":dsad,}]"
```

to

```
"[{"enc":dsad}]"
```

Scripts won't work in IE unless you remove the trailing  comma of the last element in your array. Did your browser console (F12) throw you an error?

Comment: The comma isn't the only problem, see comments to question

Answer (score 0):

**BEFORE QUESTION EDIT**

There are two problems with your JSON...

1. Object properties that are split with a comma should not contain a trailing comma (missing final property)
2. Object property values should be one of the following types: `string, number, object, array, true, false, null` ([as explained here](http://www.json.org/))

That means the correct JSON from your example should be:

```
[{"enc":"dsad"}]
```

NOTE: The quotes wrapping your example are likely just your browser console outputting a string, those quotes are unlikely to be there really - if they are, then you need to remove them.

**AFTER QUESTION EDIT**

Since the update to the question, the newly provided JSON example is valid with the exception of the wrapping quotes. These need to be removed and can be done with the following javascript:

```
data = data.substring(1, data.length - 1);
```

[Here is a useful tool](http://jsonlint.com/) for validating JSON